# BlackBerry Spatial Database

Tags: database, mobile, blackberry, geolocation, spatial

I'm trying to create a BlackBerry app with my own geospatial database. The app shouldn't use online services, so the database should be inside the app. I just have some polygons and asking the database if I'm inside or near a polygon. Is there any good database that supports spatial data for blackberry?

Comment: What the question is?

Answer (score 0):

[Sqlite](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/8682/SQLite_overview_701956_11.jsp) runs on BlackBerry, and there are spatial extensions for it called [SpatiaLite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/). I have no idea how hard it would be to get SpatiaLite ported to BlackBerry, however, having no BlackBerry development experience myself.

There is also [libspatialindex](http://libspatialindex.github.io/) which would allow you to add a spatial index to any flat file or existing embedded database format such as [leveldb](http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/) or [cdb](http://cr.yp.to/cdb.html).